# MS Access VBA temporarily highlight field

Tags: ms-access, vba

When a user switches between records on a sub form, I want another field to highlight temporarily to catch the eye to alert the user that it has changed.

I would think that this would work:

```
Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
```

---

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
    Form_frm_Codes.txtCodeToAdd = Me.Code.Value
    Form_frm_Codes.txtCodeToAdd.BackColor = RGB(0, 0, 255)
    Sleep (500)
    Form_frm_Codes.txtCodeToAdd.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
End Sub
```

The sleep function tends to pause the program for half a second, but I don't see the blue change imediately before.

Any ideas or even a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using API try below code

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
    Form_frm_Codes.txtCodeToAdd = Me.Code.Value
    Form_frm_Codes.txtCodeToAdd.BackColor = RGB(0, 0, 255)
    delay 5
    Form_frm_Codes.txtCodeToAdd.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
End Sub

Private Sub delay(seconds As Long)
    Dim endTime As Date
    endTime = DateAdd("s", seconds, Now())
    Do While Now() < endTime
        DoEvents
    Loop
End Sub
```

OR add DoEvents before sleep to update the screen.

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
    Form_frm_Codes.txtCodeToAdd = Me.Code.Value
    Form_frm_Codes.txtCodeToAdd.BackColor = RGB(0, 0, 255)
    DoEvents
    Sleep (500)
    Form_frm_Codes.txtCodeToAdd.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
End Sub
```